# SharedPreferences push

Tags: android, android-studio

Me gustaria guardar mis mensajes push en SharedPreferences y despues enseñarlos en un layout como se podria enpezar.

Utilizo firebase cloud messaging para el envio de los mensajes push.

Comment: Hola Jorge Para que deseas guardar tus mensajes de push notifications en preferencias? es un poco raro tu peticion.

Comment: Me gustaria guardalos para enseñalos luego en un layout

Comment: Jorje, si lo que quieres es mostrarlos más tarde por que no usar directamente la BD de Firebase? De esa manera se sincroniza en tiempo real y las puedes mostrar mas adelante ( de hecho hay Adapters ya hechos para leer nodos de Firebase)

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta, que expone un poco el uso de sharedprefences

Comment: no sería mejor guardarlos en BD?

Answer (score 2):

Para usar `SharedPreferences` primero tienes que cargar el gestor con:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("TAG_APP_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

### Guardar datos

Para guardar un valor se define un editor del gestor.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

Ahora ya puedes almacenar datos, por ejemplo una cadena se haria:

```
editor.putString("DJ","Paco Pil");
```

Se puede almacenar otros tipos de datos

`putBoolean, putFloat, putInt, putLong, putString`

Una vez añadidos los datos al editor, se deben guardar, se realiza con:

```
editor.apply()
```

### Obtener datos

Para obtener datos se hace directamente des de el gestor definido para `SharedPreferences`

```
String DJName = preferences.getString("DJ", "");
Log.d("debug, "El valor de DJ es: " + DjName);
```

*Ten en cuenta que si no existe `DJ` dentro de las `SharedPreferences` se le otorgara el valor por defecto del segundo parámetro, en este caso `""`*

### Ejemplo funcional

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("TAG_APP_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Escribir datos en el gestor
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("DJ","Paco Pil");
editor.putString()
editor.apply();

//Leer datos del gestor
String name = preferences.getString("DJ", "");
Log.d(TAG, "El valor de DJ es: " + name);
```